# Android layout-weight:How to explain the calculation of proportion when width set 'match_parent'

Tags: android, layout, android-layout-weight

I'm new to android.When learning about the 'weight' property of layout,I got confused.
I know that when the `layout_width` is set to **0dp**,each element will occupy `weight/weightSum`.
But when the `layout_width` is set to **match_parrent**(perhaps not recommended though),it's a little complicated.
Somebody says the formula is:

> delta = 1-numOfElement;
>   proportion[ i ] = 1+delta*(weight[ i ]/weightSum);

Let me give an example to make it clear~

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_cancel"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
    <Button
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

There are 3 elements,so delta=1-3=-2;
weightSum=(2+3+4)=9;
proportion[ 0 ] = 1+(-2)*(2/9)=5/9;

proportion[ 1 ] = 1+(-2)*(3/9)=3/9;
proportion[ 2 ] = 1+(-2)*(4/9)=1/9;

> So it's actually 5:3:1

But I don't understand the meaning,could anybody explain that?~
Or if the formula is wrong,please correct it~Thanks

Comment: i changed my answer to your specific issue @disinuo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are 2 views in the LinearLayout, the first with a layout_weight of 1, the second with a layout_weight of 2 and no weightSum is specified, by default, the weightSum is calculated to be 3 (sum of the weights of the children) and the first view takes 1/3 of the space while the second takes 2/3.

However, if we were to specify the weightSum as 5, the first would take 1/5th of the space while the second would take 2/5th. So a total of 3/5th of the space would be occupied by the layout keeping the rest empty.

```
Calculation to assign any Remaining/Extra space between child. (not the total space)

space assign to child = (child individual weight) / (sum of weight of every child in Linear Layout)
```

if any one of the children is given 0 weight then it takes up the minimum space required to render and rest of available space is distributed among the children  by the above formula

The Reverse expansion takes place in your case since:
because you are using match_parent as the layout_width. The weight is used to distribute the remaining empty space,and your first element has match parent therefore it tries to occupy the highest space horizontally and remaining lesser space is distributed among two other children.

Again for the second child,it tries to expand to the maximum space available leaving a very less space for the last child,therefore expansion is totally reverse to the applied individual weights.

In other words,
match_parent dominates like a boss in this case.
No specific calculation appears here rather Priority to the children in order can be seen very clearly.

Comment: I think maybe the examples you showed are conditions when `layout_width=0dp`?~   My question is when `layout_wdith="match_parent"`

Comment: i changed my answer to your specific issue @disinuo

Comment: So in that case `weight` seems like `priority`.The less it is,the more it gets~But I still wonder the meaning of the formula I posted.What's the meaning of `delta`

Comment: it's more of a relative measure of the weights of the other children too

Comment: I am not sure about what the delta express in the formula but it seems android doesn't follow a particular formula when you provide match parent to all the children

Comment: Alright then~Perhaps I won't use weight that way.I will just set width to 0dp. Thanks~ ^ ^